# How to create template for content part created in admin in an orchard site

Tags: templates, orchardcms

I am new with Orchard and can not seem to get past this problem.

### Goal

1. to be able to specify two text values on each page and show those in a styled DIV if they are not blank.

### Procedure

1. I created a new **content part** in Orchard's admin named
   "**InnerPageTitleArea**"
2. I added two **fields** to this part: **IpTitle (Text Field)** and **IpSubtitle
   (Text Field)**
3. I added this part to the Page content type
4. Those textboxes show when editing a page, and I filled them in on
   several pages
5. Those values show on pages they were entered on (all good so far)

### The problem:

1. I want to provide a template for the InnerPageTitleArea, but all
   attempts have failed.
2. When using shape tracing, there are no alternates referencing my
   part alone
3. All alternates begin with "Fields" i.e.
   **~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Fields.Common.Text-InnerPageTitleArea.cshtml**.
4. If I use one of those field alternates, my template is repeated
   twice - once for each field
5. If I use a field-specific template, i.e.
   **~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Fields.Common.Text-InnerPageTitleArea-IpTitle.cshtml**
   I can actually get at both values, but then the other value
   (IpSubtitle) still displays as plain text.  I could probably remedy
   that with Placement.info, but I suspect that I am just lacking some
   fundamental understand of Orchard.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your part never renders anything because it doesn't have a driver that would create a shape. The only shapes that are getting out of that part are the shapes for each of the fields. The simplest way to get what you want is to create one alternate for each of the fields. Would that work?

Comment: Thanks for the info, that helps my understanding.  I don't think creating alternates for each field is the way to go because because I need them both contained in the same div.  I suppose I could do everything in one of the alternates, then create a blank alternate for the second, but that smells a bit.  Is the preferred approach to create a new part type in code?

Comment: Instead of a blank alternate, you can send the shape for that field to "-" using placement.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Is it that Orchard cannot bend to allow the creation of `.cshtml` alternates for Content Parts, or just something that has not been coded into the framework (assuming it can be)?

Comment: Sorry, asking that question I remembered an old blog I saw a while back and just found: http://kobowi.co.uk/blog/2012/11/content-display-type-alternates-for-content-parts-in-orchard/. So @jcomet you would have to code your wanted alternates.